# Is it a good design option to call a class' initializing method within a factory before injecting it

Tags: c#, refactoring, factory-pattern

I am in the process of refactoring a rather large portion of spaghetti code. In a nutshell it is a big "God-like" class that branches into two different processes depending in some condition. Both processes are lengthy and have lots of duplicated code.

So my first effort has been to extract those two processes into their own classes and putting the common code in a parent they both inherit from.

It looks something like this:

```
public class ExportProcess
{
   public ExportClass(IExportDataProvider dataProvider, IExporterFactory exporterFactory)
   {
       _dataProvider = dataProvider;
       _exporterFactory = exporterFactory;
   }

   public void DoExport(SomeDataStructure someDataStructure)
   {
      _dataProvider.Load(someDataStructure.Id);

      var exporter = _exporterFactory.Create(_dataProvider, someDataStructure);

      exporter.Export();
   }
}
```

I am an avid reader of Mark Seemann's blog and in [this entry](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling.aspx) he explains that this code has a temporal coupling smell since it is necessary to call the Load method on the data provider before it is in a usable state.

Based on that, and since the object is being injected to the ones returned by the factory anyway, I am thinking of changing the factory to do this:

```
public IExporter Create(IExportDataProvider dataProvider, SomeDataStructure someDataStructure)
{
   dataProvider.Load(someDataStructure.Id);

   if(dataProvider.IsNewExport)
   {
      return new NewExportExporter(dataProvider, someDataStructure);
   }
   return new UpdateExportExporter(dataProvider, someDataStructure);
}
```

Because of the name "DataProvider" you probably guessed that the Load method is actually doing a database access.

Something tells me an object doing a database access inside the create method of an abstract factory is not a good design.

Are there any guidelines, best practices or something that say this is effectively a bad idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Obviously dataProvider.Load has some kind of side effect, along the lines of fetching an instance of something into a property? Does the rest of the factory-method actually use `dataProvider` and `someDataStructure`? If it does not, then your arguments to the factory-method should be refactored into accepting the arguments it really needs.

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand: Good point Patrik. The objects that are created by the factory do, in fact, use the data provider heavily since its Load method does populate quite a few properties that are needed. This is a very first refactoring effort but, unfortunately this is a piece of technical debt that might not get paid in the shorter run.

Comment: ok, consider this then: If dataProvider.Load would be called multiple times, would that create any issues? **If no**: Cool, I'd move the `Load`-call into the factory method since it will simplify clients (all calls to .Load would be inside the factory method).   **If yes**: You've got no choice but to keep it outside the factory, since you can't know whether it is initialized or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, a factory is used to resolve concrete types of a requested interface or abstract type, so you can decouple consumers from implementation. So usually a factory is just going to discover or specify the concrete type, help resolve dependencies, and instantiate the concrete type and return it. However, there's no hard or fast rule as to what it can or can't do, but it is sensible to give it enough access to only to resources that it needs to resolve and instantiate concrete types.

Another good use of a factory is to hide from consumers types dependencies that are not relevant to the consumer. For example, it seems `IExportDataProvider` is only relevant internally, and can be abstracted away from consumers (such as `ExportProcess`).

One code smell in your example, however, is how `IExportDataProvider` is used. The way it currently seems to work, you get an instance of it once, but it's possible to change its state in subsequent usages (by calling `Load`). This can lead to issues with concurrency and corrupted state. Since I don't know what that type does or how it's actually used by your `IExporter`, it's hard to make a recommendation. In my example below, I make an adjustment so that we can assume that the provider is stateless, and instead `Load` returns some sort of state object that the factory can use to resolve the concrete type of exporter, and then provide data to it. You can adjust that as you see fit. On the other hand, if the provider has to be stateful, you'll want to create an `IExportDataProviderFactory`, use it in your exporter factory, and create a new instance of the provider from the factory for each call to exporter factory's `Create`.

```
public interface IExporterFactory
{
    IExporter Create(SomeDataStructure someData);
}

public class MyConcreteExporterFactory : IExporterFactory
{
     public MyConcreteExporterFactory(IExportDataProvider provider) 
     {
          if (provider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

          Provider = provider;
     }

     public IExportDataProvider Provider { get; private set; }      

     public IExporter Create(SomeDataStructure someData)
     {
         var providerData = Provider.Load(someData.Id);

         // do whatever. for example...
         return providerData.IsNewExport ? new NewExportExporter(providerData, someData) : new UpdateExportExporter(providerData, someData);
     }
}
```

And then consume:

```
public class ExportProcess
{
    public ExportProcess(IExporterFactory exporterFactory)
    {
        if (exporterFactory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        _exporterFactory = factory;
    }

    private IExporterFactory _exporterFactory;

    public void DoExport(SomeDataStructure someData)
    {
        var exporter = _exporterFactory.Create(someData);
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: There is one problem with your example. The provider loads a few properties of different types with different data. If I separate all those calls so that each method returns the data that it queried then the Concrete Exporter constructor will have quite a few parameters. I know this is an indication that the class is still doing too much. With these thoughts in mind, do you still consider this to be the best option?

Comment: @SergioRomero In that case, you might consider an adapter. Let the factory be used for resolving the kind of IExporter you need, and use an adapter to actually broker the creation of the IExporter. I'll see if I can update my answer with an example of what I mean.